# Almost same code running much slower

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Given a string array words, find the maximum value of length(word[i]) * length(word[j]) where the two words do not share common letters. You may assume that each word will contain only lower case letters. If no such two words exist, return 0.

https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-product-of-word-lengths/

You can create a bitmap of char for each word to check if they share chars in common and then calc the max product.

I have two method almost equal but the first pass checks, while the second is too slow, can you understand why?

```
class Solution {
public:

    int maxProduct2(vector<string>& words) {
        int len = words.size();
        int *num = new int[len];
        // compute the bit O(n)
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i ++) {
            int k = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < words[i].length(); j ++) {
                k = k | (1 <<(char)(words[i].at(j)));
            }
            num[i] = k;
        }
        int c = 0;
        // O(n^2)
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i ++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j ++) {
                if ((num[i] & num[j]) == 0) { // if no common letters
                    int x = words[i].length() * words[j].length();
                    if (x > c) {
                        c = x;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        delete []num;
        return c;
    }

    int maxProduct(vector<string>& words) {
        vector<int> bitmap(words.size());
        for(int i=0;i<words.size();++i) {
            int k = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<words[i].length();++j) {
                 k |= 1 << (char)(words[i][j]);
            }
            bitmap[i] = k;
        }

        int maxProd = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<words.size()-1;++i) {
            for(int j=i+1;j<words.size();++j) {
                if ( !(bitmap[i] & bitmap[j])) {
                    int x = words[i].length() * words[j].length();
                    if ( x > maxProd  )
                        maxProd = x;
                }
            }
        }
        return maxProd;
    }
};
```

Why the second function (maxProduct) is too slow for leetcode?

### Solution

The second method does repetitive call to words.size(). If you save that in a var than it working fine

Comment: well, you've got a loop that does (number of words)² checks; that'd be a start... How many words are there?

Comment: Also you *call* it bitmap, but in fact, it's a `vector<int>`, not a thing composed of individually adressable bits.

Comment: Consider the case where all words have common letters and count the number of multiplications each function is making.

Comment: @molbdnilo: now the multiplication is done only after the if, like the first code. but still it's too slow

Comment: @MarcusMüller: it's almost the same as the first one (the first use an array)

Comment: gio, what do you think does `max` in your second implementation actually *do*, and what complexity does that operation have? to repeat my hint: We know the complexity of the first nested loop. what's the overall complexity of the second set of nested loops?

Comment: also, why the hell is this tagged [tag:java]? I think you should remove that tag.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I have edited the second loop, now it's almost the same as the first method. Still it's slower. I am not sure if I got what you mean

Comment: You edited away the `max` and that should have been the core problem here.

Comment: `k = k | (1 <<(char)(words[i].at(j)));` seems strange (and should be UB). should it be `k = k | (1 <<(char)(words[i].at(j) - 'a'));` instead ?

Comment: @Jarod42: I thought the same, but if you try that code strangely it works. Try it in leetcode

Comment: @MarcusMüller: leetcode says it's still slow

Comment: well, we're not leetcode. How fast is it on *your* computer, compared to the other implementation? Profile.

Comment: I see two things that jump out. One is that you're using a vector and not an array, which in certain cases can be significantly slower. The second is that the first solution calls `words.size()` once and then uses the result multiple places. The second calls it in the loop checks, which is likely hurting your pipelining and branch checks significantly.

Comment: I tried replacing the vector with the array with no luck. For words.size() I think that's constant time lookup so I don't think it changes much

Comment: @kchinger: I saved words.size() in a variable and now it works ok. How is that possibile that words.size() slows down so much?

Comment: @giò I made an answer to explain what's happening. Constant time just means there is an upper bound regardless of problem size. It doesn't necessarily mean fast.

Comment: With optimization turn on, `words.size()` should be computed out of the loop. Probably the UB with `1 << 97` to `1 << 122` change generated code and optimization done.

Comment: @Jarod42: is `1 <<(char)(words[i].at(j)));` UB? I don't think since the code works

Comment: @giò: working is one possible output of UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment turned out to be correct I'll turn my comment into an answer and try to explain what I think is happening.

I wrote some simple code to benchmark on my own machine with two solutions of two loops each. The only difference is the call to words.size() is inside the loop versus outside the loop. The first solution is approximately 13.87 seconds versus 16.65 seconds for the second solution. This isn't huge, but it's about 20% slower.

Even though vector.size() is a constant time operation that doesn't mean it's as fast as just checking against a variable that's already in a register. Constant time can still have large variances. When inside nested loops that adds up.

The other thing that *could* be happening (someone much smarter than me will probably chime in and let us know) is that you're hurting your CPU optimizations like branching and pipelining. Every time it gets to the end of the the loop it has to stop, wait for the call to size() to return, and then check the loop variable against that return value. If the cpu can look ahead and guess that `j` is still going to be less than `len` because it hasn't seen `len` change (`len` isn't even inside the loop!) it can make a good branch prediction each time and not have to wait.

Comment: Not sure how you test it, but the `vector` version zero initialize `bitmap`, whereas the other the buffer is left uninitialized before assignment.

Comment: @jarod42 I tested with a vector that I initialized before timing, then timed two identical sets of two loops working on that vector, and the only difference was the `.size()` was in the compare or done once first. The second loop was the slower, despite having the advantage of going second on the same vector and doing the same thing.